# How to add two datagrid view(dt1 and dt2) row values to a new datagrid view dt3 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two `datagridview` tables: *dt1* and *dt2*. I want to combine the value *dt1* and *dt2* and put the combined value to new `datagridview` *dt3*.

If first value for *dt1* is 0000 and *dt2* is 02, the value in *dt3* should be as 0000,02

Follows my code:

```
For c = 0 To DataDataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
     For t = 0 To DataDataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
         DataGridView3.Rows.Add(DataDataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(0).Value)
     Next
Next
```

Comment: If you are wanting to add **both** from dgv1 and dgv2, why do you only use values from dgv1? `Value` is an Object so you should append the `ToString` method to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are after. The names are slightly different since I stuck with the defaults.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("0000")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("0001")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("0002")

    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("02")
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("04")
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add("06")

    For c = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 '2 because of the extra row used for editing
        For t = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
            DataGridView3.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "," & DataGridView2.Rows(t).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Output as follows:

[image: Sub output]